# How to set list view scroll position is end for uneven rows set to true in list view in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my application requirement of the show last item in a listview but I am unable to do that. I have tried following ways but no luck.

1. I have tried with scrollTo method set to end position and last item given to the method.
2. I have tried with scrollTo method set to scroll position make visible.

Please suggest any idea to set scrolling position of a listview set bottom initially. Thanks in advance.

### Case 1 :

```
     var v = MessagesList.ItemsSource.Cast<ChatModel>().LastOrDefault();

     MessagesList.ScrollTo(v, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
```

### Case 2 :

```
    var lastItem = _chatViewModel.MessagesList[_chatViewModel.MessagesList.Count - 1];

    MessagesList.ScrollTo(lastItem, ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, true);
```

I have tried above two solutions for getting scroll view set at bottom of the listview.

Comment: You want to scroll down to the last list item?

Comment: yes, I want to show last item in a list.

Comment: If you have not solved this problem, you can custom `ListView` to test.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it something like this:

```
  var v = _listView.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().LastOrDefault();
  _listView.ScrollTo(v, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
```

Comment: I have tried above code but no luck. It doesn't show the last item in list view.

Comment: Okay then what happens?

Comment: I have modified my code with your given code but no change, scroll position set at first item position (list view scroll position at starting item of list view).

Comment: I have updated question, can you please look at once.

Comment: In which method are you calling this?

Comment: After assigning list to itemsource of listview, I have called above method.

Comment: Yeah so that could be the issue that as soon as you are assigning data you are doing this i would add this code at the end of the method so that the listview is properly initialized when you call the method

Comment: No, I have called scroll to end method after assigning a list of data to the list view items source.

Comment: Yeah that is what i am saying that do it a little late in the lifecycle to the list view is already formed when you do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184635/discussion-between-g-hakim-and-deepak).